# Action Bar messed up after using setTitle

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am trying to set the title of the actionBar in a activity. I have 3 layout views in one activity. Each View Layout shows a different state of the payment process. Now that I set the title, at one stage the actionbar background gets messed up. I wonder why.

This does not happen if I comment out the following line.

```
onClick() {
....
    getActionBar().setTitle("Customer Payment");
....
```

In the onCreate of the activity I run the following to setup the actionbar background.

```
private void setupActionBar() {
    Drawable backgroundColor;
    switch (getIntent().getIntExtra(God.HOME_SCREEN_OPERATION,
            God.INVALID_ID)) {
    case God.OPERATION_RECHARGE:
        getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.icon_mobile);
        backgroundColor = new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(
                R.color.RechargeBackgroundColor));
        getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(backgroundColor);
        mobileServiceSummary.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        serviceInfoLayout.setBackground(backgroundColor);
        serviceInfoIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_mobile);
        break;
    case God.OPERATION_FACILITY:
        getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.icon_facility);
        backgroundColor = new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(
                R.color.ToiletBackgroundColor));
        getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(backgroundColor);
        facilityServiceSummary.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        serviceInfoLayout.setBackground(backgroundColor);
        serviceInfoIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_facility);
        break;
    case God.OPERATION_DTH:
        getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.icon_dth);
        backgroundColor = new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(
                R.color.DthBackgroundColor));
        getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(backgroundColor);
        dthServiceSummary.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        serviceInfoLayout.setBackground(backgroundColor);
        serviceInfoIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_dth);
        break;
    // case R.id.mseb_payment:
    // getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.icon_mseb);
    // msebServiceSummary.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) ;
    // break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Some more code..

```
private void enableCustomerPayment() {
        getActionBar().setTitle("Customer Payment");
        getActionBar().setSubtitle(
                "Pincode of customer needed for payment permission.");
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        getActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(false) ;
        getActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false) ;

        findViewById(R.id.next_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.payment_button).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.done_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);

        operatorLockLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        customerLoginAndConfirmationLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        customerPaymentLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        customerConfirmLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        // customerConfirmSpaceLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    private void enablePaymentConfirmation() {
        getActionBar().setTitle("Payment Confirmation");
        getActionBar().setSubtitle("Thankyou for your payment.");
        setupActionBar();
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);

        findViewById(R.id.next_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.payment_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.done_button).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        operatorLockLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        customerLoginAndConfirmationLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        customerPaymentLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        customerConfirmLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        // customerConfirmSpaceLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

In styles.xml the color's are setup like this. And the colors are working fine.

```
<color name="NewWalletBackgroundColor">#FFD54E</color>
<color name="BalanceBackgroundColor">#FFD54E</color>
<color name="DepositBackgroundColor">#FFD54E</color>
<color name="MsebBackgroundColor">#E57272</color>
<color name="RechargeBackgroundColor">#81C784</color>
<color name="DthBackgroundColor">#AB6BAC</color>
<color name="ToiletBackgroundColor">#56C0ED</color>
```

## The Action Bar is messed up

[image]

## Here, the Action Bar background is completely blue. This is what I expect.

[image]

## Edit

> Seems like there is a issue with the height, it starts up with 96 and when its messed up the height is 0.

How do I fix this now ?

Comment: More code for the action bar

Comment: what is the expected output you want ? can you please add the final image .So that i can get an idea then i will add my custom code that i used earlier.

Comment: I expect the entire action bar to get a background color. I wonder why there is this gap.

Comment: in the other view have you the blue actionbar you want ?

Comment: yes.. i need it full blue..

Comment: @Siddharth : I created a sample based on your code, and its working fine, if possible please post Activity code.

Comment: added more code..hope it helps

Comment: @Siddharth : Thanks for the additional code, I added the additional code to my sample it is working fine. I would suggest you, to post whole code of the activity so that we could debug it.

Comment: hmm do you have a problem using Toolbar? try `getActionBar().getHeight` when this happens and check it with the height when its normal

Comment: @Siddharth need more code, from  app theme. I think there is some issue in your theme. Or try to implement actionbar with toolbar(https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html)

Comment: Codes by which you've changed the background color seems to be okay. Please post full codes that this `onClick` method is belonged to.

Comment: @Siddharth use the Toolbar.

Comment: @Elltz thanks, its a height problem. When its messed up it becomes 0. If I fix it, that should be it.

Comment: @Elltz any idea on how to fix the height issue..

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the default action bar is expecting an icon for the navigation drawer icon on the right of action bar. I think there is a transparent button on the space you are talking about. Even if you set the drawer for this activity or not it will be there if you use default methods to set the action bar.First try these steps

```
  setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false).
  actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false) 
  actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
```

If that does not work go for a custom action bar.

Do something like this. Instead of using the default actionbar why do not you try to set a custom view (plain TextView where its width is set to match parent).

```
       this.getActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
       this.getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

       LayoutInflater inflator = LayoutInflater.from(this);
       View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.titleview, null);

      //if you need to customize anything else about the text, do it here.
      ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.title)).setText(this.getTitle());

      //assign the view to the actionbar
      this.getActionBar().setCustomView(v);
```

Comment: could not find the method  setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false).

Comment: so you are not using a navigation drawer here right? cuz that method comes for the drawerToggle class. Have you tried second method?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming from your question that the  `enablePaymentConfirmation` is working code with `getActionBar().setTitle("Customer Payment");` present and when it is commented out. If it too is playing up, then I will need to alter my answer.

Not seeing your xml makes it a bit more guess work, but from I can see, I would suggest the following.
1.
Call `setupActionBar()` from you `OnCreate` in your activity. This way it is set up for the duration of your activity. By not calling it in OnCreate if you call `enableCustomerPayment()` before `enablePaymentConfirmation()`, the actionbar setup will not have been called.

2.
Unless the following change in code you have not shown, these can go in your setupActionbar:

```
 getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
 getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
```

3.
These are the two changes to the ActionBar between the two methods you show:

```
getActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(false) ;
getActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false) ;
```

4.
I am not sure why you are only setting `setDisplayShowCustomEnabled` in your `enableCustomerPayment()`. I cannot see that you are using a customView. 
- If not that can also go into your setup. 
- Otherwise you will need to call it in all your methods with the changes. 
- If you are using a custom view for your actionbar in some places and not others, this will be affecting how it is displayed. Particularly if you are not managing the bool changes.

5.
Same goes for the logo, I don't see where you are using it. So I would put it in setup. If you are using it for the others and you haven't got your xml set up correctly, it could be why there is a difference in the background color.

Hope this helps. Feel free to post more info, xml would be good.